# different interpretation of the dot in the order by C # linq and ORACLE

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-order-by

**With ORACLE**

```
select * from (
select 'LM.CHARLET' c from dual
union
select 'L.MOURLIN' c from dual
union
select 'Y.LEFEUVRE' c from dual
union
select 'S.MIRO' c from dual
) order by c
```

RETURN

- **LM.CHARLET**
- L.MOURLIN
- S.MIRO
- Y.LEFEUVRE

**But with C#**

```
List<string> testLst = new List<string> { "LM.CHARLET", "L.MOURLIN", "Y.LEFEUVRE", "S.MIRO" };
List<string> orderedLst = testLst.OrderBy (p => p).ToList ();
```

RETURN

- L.MOURLIN
- **LM.CHARLET**
- S.MIRO
- Y.LEFEUVRE

does anyone have an explanation for this difference ?

Comment: Oracle sorting is described here: [Linguistic Sorting and Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG269), this you have to compare with Microsoft documents - happy reading :)

Comment: I tested with all values StringComparer's parameter but i get the same result order. So different from ORACLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, the ordering depends on the [Collation settings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-B0971B89-63EF-409B-B14A-459B8211E764):

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=BINARY;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY;

select *
from   (
  select 'LM.CHARLET' AS c from dual union
  select 'L.MOURLIN'  from dual union
  select 'Y.LEFEUVRE' from dual union
  select 'S.MIRO'     from dual
)
order by c
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | C          |
> | :--------- |
> | L.MOURLIN  |
> | LM.CHARLET |
> | S.MIRO     |
> | Y.LEFEUVRE |
> ```

and:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=FRENCH;

select *
from   (
  select 'LM.CHARLET' AS c from dual union
  select 'L.MOURLIN'  from dual union
  select 'Y.LEFEUVRE' from dual union
  select 'S.MIRO'     from dual
)
order by c
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | C          |
> | :--------- |
> | LM.CHARLET |
> | L.MOURLIN  |
> | S.MIRO     |
> | Y.LEFEUVRE |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7050ec58a35444d73494a95975f5ac42)*

It appears that your Oracle session is using linguistic collation and sorting while [C# is using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) the [Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1.default?view=netframework-4.8) comparer. Change either Oracle's collation settings or the comparer you're using in C# so that the sorting uses the same method in both.

In Oracle, you could use the `NLSSORT` function in the `ORDER BY` to override the session defaults:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=FRENCH;

select *
from   (
  select 'LM.CHARLET' AS c from dual union
  select 'L.MOURLIN'  from dual union
  select 'Y.LEFEUVRE' from dual union
  select 'S.MIRO'     from dual
)
order by NLSSORT( c, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY' );
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | C          |
> | :--------- |
> | L.MOURLIN  |
> | LM.CHARLET |
> | S.MIRO     |
> | Y.LEFEUVRE |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e01ffbc8459f3ddb8b6c9c60c2c9d506)*